# How to create directory to IPFS by using "ipfs-http-client"?

Tags: ipfs

Now I am trying to create new directory to ipfs by using "ipfs-http-client"?
const auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(projectId + ':' + projectSecret).toString('base64')
const ipfs = new ipfsAPI({
host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
port: 5001,
protocol: 'https',
headers: {
authorization: auth
}
});
ipfs.files.mkdir("/myfolder");

but I have got error."ipfs method not supported".
Did anyone see that in the past?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were trying to use some outdated version of the module, try this code, it worked for me:

```
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'
const auth = 'Basic' + Buffer.from('projectId' + ':' + 'secret').toString('base64');
const ipfs = create({host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https', headers: { authorization: auth } });
let result = await ipfs.files.mkdir("/myfolder");
```

Comment: that is not working

Comment: @pongpong what error do you get?

Comment: @MimoKrok I used your suggestion and I am also getting "ipfs method not supported." I am using `^55.0.0` for the library. Do you have any debugging suggestions? `ipfs.add` and `ipfs.cat` are working.

Comment: @MimoKrok [this post](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/connecting-to-remote-ipfs-node/8377) says Infura does not support MFS. Looks like that may be the problem. Were you using a different host by chance?

Comment: No, not really, the code I posted is exactly the one I used